# Pass jquery var to a function in functions.php

Tags: functions, ajax

I have this js in /js/functions.js:

```
     jQuery(document).ready( function($){
  //Some event will trigger the ajax call, you can push whatever data to the server, simply passing it to the "data" object in ajax call
  $.ajax({
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object instantiated in wp_localize_script function
    type: 'POST',
    data:{
      action: 'myaction', // this is the function in your functions.php that will be triggered
      name: 'John',
      age: '38'
    },
    success: function( data ){
      //Do something with the result from server
      console.log( data );
    }
  });
});
```

And in functions.php I have:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'so18550905_enqueue_scripts' );
function so18550905_enqueue_scripts(){
  wp_register_script( 'ajaxHandle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array(), false, true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajaxHandle' );
  wp_localize_script( 'ajaxHandle', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction', 'so18550905_wp_ajax_function' );
function so18550905_wp_ajax_function(){
  //DO whatever you want with data posted
  //To send back a response you have to echo the result!
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['age'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}
?>
```

But I can't echo name and age on front pages.

Where is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Where would it echo? `AJAX` is happening on admin side, not client-facing side, in background.

Comment: And how can I use $_POST['name'] and $_POST['age']? For example, if I want that if ($_POST['name']=='Jhon') then echo a DIV in a public file not in admin.

Comment: The AJAX request should be expecting the PHP function to return a response. So you'd need to put everything together (after verifying it's all kosher) into an array (or string if you've not much to say) and `return` it

Comment: if you're just printing the response somewhere, you don't have to return something, an echo should (and does) work fine. even if the response is a json object you can echo it. do you get any javascript errors in console? do you see your script and javascript object when you view page source?

Comment: I would like to print $_POST['name'] in my WordPress home page. How can I do it?

Comment: There is no errors in console. I wouldlike to work with the response values to print different things in my home page.

Comment: have you verified that the script and localization data is printed to the page and that your ajax function is even firing?

Comment: Yes, I have verified.